# QT Creator will only convert the first word from text Edit to plain text

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, fstream, qtextedit

This is a notes program, you write in the `textEdit` and it saves it using `fstream`. I am trying to figure out how to load back ALL the words previously typed on the `textEdit`, right now only the first word loads back. I think it has something to do with the white spaces.

```
 #include "mainwindow.h"
 #include "ui_mainwindow.h"
 #include <fstream>

 using namespace std;

 MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
 QMainWindow(parent),
 ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
 {
     ui->setupUi(this);

     // Setup code
    ui->textEdit->setReadOnly(true);
    ui->textEdit->append("Select one of the buttons on the left to pick a log");
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

string buttons;
string lastSavedText[] =
{
    " ",
    " "
};

QString qLastSavedTextHome, qLastSavedTextWork;
```

This is the first button

```
void MainWindow::on_homeButton_clicked()
{
    // Preparing text edit
    ui->textEdit->setReadOnly(false);
    ui->textEdit->clear();
    ui->textEdit->setOverwriteMode(true);
    buttons = "Home";

    // Loading previously saved text
    ifstream home;
    home.open("home.apl");
    home >> lastSavedText[0];
    home.close();

    qLastSavedTextHome = QString::fromStdString(lastSavedText[0]);
    ui->textEdit->setPlainText(qLastSavedTextHome);
 }
```

This next button isn't fully developed yet:

```
 void MainWindow::on_workButton_clicked()
 {
     // Preparing text edit
     ui->textEdit->setReadOnly(false);
     ui->textEdit->clear();
     buttons = "Work";

     // Converts textEdit to string
     QString textEditText = ui->textEdit->toPlainText();
     string plainText = textEditText.toStdString();
 }
```

This is where I convert the `textEdit` to a string and save the `textEdit` to a stream:

```
 void MainWindow::on_saveButton_clicked()
 {

     // Converts textEdit to string
     QString textEditText = ui->textEdit->toPlainText();
     lastSavedText[0] = textEditText.toStdString();

     // Saving files
     ofstream home;
     home.open("home.apl");
     home << lastSavedText[0];
     home.close();
 }
```

Comment: Only the first word loads back when the program is reopened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading only one word in your code:

```
ifstream home;
home.open("home.apl");
home >> lastSavedText[0]; // Here!!!
home.close();
```

I'd suggest that you use [`QFile`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html) for reading and writing to file and it'll be more easier to do.

**Here's an example:**

```
QFile file { "home.apl" };
if ( !file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text) )
{
    qDebug() << "Could not open file!";
    return;
}

const auto& lastSavedText = file.readAll();
file.close();

ui->textEdit->setPlainText( lastSavedText );
```

You should use Qt features as much you can. You can directly use `QString` instead of `std::string` and you won't have to do those conversions.

Comment: Thank you so much! I just tried it out and it worked, thanks for your help!

Comment: @DylanMcClish: You are welcome! :) Kindly accept the answer.